# Bibtex Key definition

Tags: bibtex, citing, keywords

I only recently started using Latex for my university documents and for my current one I am using a template provided by them.

I am using bibtex to manage my sources. Here is an example bibtex-entry:

```
@misc{webpage1,
   shorthand = {CompanyName},
   author = {Company Name Ltd.},
   title="The company's webplatform",
   howpublished = "\url{http://company.com/}",
   lastchecked = {01.01.2013},
   year = 2013
}

@misc{webpage2,
   shorthand = {OtherCompanyName},
   author = {Some other Company Name Ltd.},
   title="Another company's webplatform",
   howpublished = "\url{http://other-company.com/}",
   lastchecked = {01.01.2013},
   year = 2013
}
```

In my Latex document I use the following code to create a bibliography:

```
\bibliography{references}    % this causes the references to be listed (file: references.bib)
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
```

My problem is now that when I compile my document, the result is that the bibliography has the following format:

```
[Ltd13a] Full Company Name Ltd.
[Ltd13b] Some Other Company Name Ltd.
```

I already tried putting a comma between the name and the Ltd. like so:

```
author = {Company Name, Ltd.}
```

but this results in this

```
[FC13a] Ltd. Full Company Name
```

I have read that shorthand is supposed to help, but I did not succeed.

Comment: What is the result that you'd like to see? I am also surprised about the Full Company name thing... Could you post a complete MWE telling us what you'd like to see?

Comment: How about putting braces around company names, in addition to the comma? `author={{Company Name}, Ltd.}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: @KevinC The thing with your solution is, that it puts the Ltd. in front in the further text, e.g.
`[Full13a] Ltd. Full Company Name`

Comment: @Steve: It probably has to do with how the `alpha` style is define (with which I'm not familiar). You should check out @Guido's updated answer with the use of `key` entry. I tested that and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried `{{Full Company Name Ltd}}`? In this way, `Full Company Name Ltd` is understood as the name. In the other ways, in the first `Ltd` is understood as the family name and `Full Company Name` as the given and mid names. For the comma, the format of names in BibTeX is `Family, Given`, so in that case `Full Company Name` is the family name and `Ltd` is  the given name.

According to the BibTeX manual `texdoc bibtex` for `MANUAL` or `PROCEEDINGS` one can use `organization` instead of `author`. In such cases the field `key` takes precedence over `organization`. Thus you can try with

```
@misc{webpage1,
   key = {CompanyName},
   organization = {Company Name, Ltd.},
   title="The company's webplatform",
   howpublished = "\url{http://company.com}",
   lastchecked = {01.01.2013},
   year = 2013
}
```

Comment: This partially solved my problem. Now the key is not starting with "Ltd" anymore.
However, I would like to completely define the key myself.

Let's assume the company is called "The Co-operative Trade Ltd."

It would be great if I could set the key to be [COOP13a] or something similar...

Comment: See the updated answer. The `key = {...}` should help.

Comment: Only the first three letters of the `key` is used, though. If you define `key={COOP}`, the output is `[COO13]`

Comment: `key = {KEY}, organization = {...}` solved the problem!

Comment: @KevinC the entire 4 letters are not that important, it was more important to change the key to something better than `The13a` or `Ltd13a`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the proper way, I propose a hack:

```
\newcommand{\Bibkeyhack}[3]{}
```

use it like

```
author = {This Is The Author\Bibkeyhack LAU}
```

Full answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377970/118593).