# How to specify bibliography alpha key without modifying the .bst file or using BibLaTeX

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

How do you tell LaTeX which alpha key to give a bibliography entry without modifying the `.bst` file?

Example: I want an entry with

```
author = {no one 910 (StackOverflow User 118593)}
```

to appear as [StO17], instead of [noSU17].

---

Working tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hereby I cite \cite{myself}.

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

bibliography.bib:

```
@misc{myself,
  author = {no one 910 (StackOverflow User 118593)},
  title = {{StackOverflow Answer}},
  howpublished = "https://stackoverflow.com",
  year = {2017}
}
```

Output:

[image: ugly bib key]

Comment: This question and your answer are completely unclear to me. What exactly are you trying to do? Can you add an actual compilable document that shows what you're doing?

Comment: Welcome! Please add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: It is really unclear to me what is going on here? What do you want to do? What is your set-up? Do you even use `biblatex`, or do you use `natbib`, BibTeX? As it stands now your question and answer is quite unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of this: [Customize appearence of citation of a specific bibliographic entry when using the alpha bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91423/2693).

Comment: Theoretically yes, but I am not allowed to change the citation style in my situation. Maybe should've added that to the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody wants to do things the proper way, here is a hack:

1. This works only with Authors that do not contain a word that starts with a lower-case letter
2. Append `\Bibkeyhack StO` to your author, with StO being the key.

Command definition: *(That's all!)*

```
\newcommand{\Bibkeyhack}[3]{}
```

If you want keys with a different length, replace 3 with your length.
For 1. there is a workaround:

```
\newcommand{\SmallHack}[1]{\lowercase{#1}}
```

Notice that both commands start upper-case, so that rule 1. is not violated.

Working example:

```
author = {\SmallHack No \SmallHack One 910 (StackOverflow User 118593)\Bibkeyhack StO}
```

Which will result in [StO17]: no one 910. Image proof:
[image: bibkey hack]

**Important**: If you put a space between `)` and `\Bibkeyhack`, the result will look like this:

[image: ugly bibkey hack]

---

Complete tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\SmallHack}[1]{\lowercase{#1}}
\newcommand{\Bibkeyhack}[3]{}
\begin{document}
Hereby I cite \cite{myself}.

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

bibliography.bib:

```
@misc{myself,
  author = {\SmallHack No \SmallHack One 910 (StackOverflow User 118593)\Bibkeyhack StO},
  title = {{StackOverflow Answer}},
  howpublished = "https://stackoverflow.com",
  year = {2017}
}
```

Output:

[image: better bib key]

Answer (score 2):

This would be very easy with `biblatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{myself,
    shorthand = {StO17},
  author = {no one 910 (StackOverflow User 118593)},
  title = {{StackOverflow Answer}},
  howpublished = "https://stackoverflow.com",
  year = {2017}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Hereby I cite \cite{myself}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know! Sadly this does not fit my requirements. I must not use BibLaTeX.

Comment: Additionaly, the year is kind of redundant in this situation, no?